# TextBox em datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Boa tarde, como adiciono um TextBox conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: Exemplo em HTML]
Já vi alguns softwares em C#/WPF com DataGrid e filtrando desta maneira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem várias soluções para o seu problema, mas na minha opinião, as melhores soluções são aquelas que usam apenas estilos com o DataGrid e controle padrão do WPF.

Algumas soluções que podem te atender:

Opção 1: [Filtragem automática de DataGrid do Toolkit de WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering)

Opção 2: [Filtro automático para o DataGrid do Microsoft WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32919/Auto-filter-for-Microsoft-WPF-DataGrid)

Opção 3: [Filtrando o DataGrid do WPF automaticamente por meio do cabeçalho](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41755/Filtering-the-WPF-DataGrid-automatically-via-the-h)

Comment: Obrigado. 
A primeira opção resolveu meu problema !

Comment: Favor ler [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/75104)